# Pandas - Convert DateTime Object To Date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas series with DateTime in the `2020-01-05D00:00:00.000000000` string format and I want to convert it into the `date` format.

I tried `pd.to_datetime(website_activity['time'])` but it is giving me the following error:

> ParserError: Unknown string format: 2020-01-05D00:00:00.000000000

What is the right format for such a DateTime stamp? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You just want to keep the date or you need the time information as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add custom string to parameter `format` in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), check https://strftime.org/:

```
website_activity = pd.DataFrame({'time':['2020-01-05D00:00:00.000000000',
                                         '2021-01-05D00:00:00.000000000']})
website_activity['time'] = (pd.to_datetime(website_activity['time'], 
                                           format='%Y-%m-%dD%H:%M:%S.%f'))
print (website_activity)
        time
0 2020-01-05
1 2021-01-05
```